# Múltiples problemas al instalar Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vscode

Tengo problemas al instalar Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, los errores que me salen son los siguientes:

[image: Multiples errores al instalar Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: Parece que todos los paquetes tienen algún tipo de error, ¿puede que estén corruptos? ¿Qué pone en el archivo de registro?

Answer (score 1):

Llegue a solucionar mi problema de la instalción, desinstale el SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition y pude instalar el Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, con toda normalidad.

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que el paquete de instalación está corrupto. ¿Por qué no te descargas la versión Visual Studio Professional para estudiantes y pequeñas empresas y pruebas a instalarla, a ver que pasa?

Enlace: [Get Visual Studio Professional for Free](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/noahc/2009/11/12/get-visual-studio-professional-for-free-for-students-and-small-businesses/)